# Bit.ly custom query - ruby gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, bit.ly

According to https://dev.bitly.com/link_metrics.html#v3_link_clicks,
we can send multiple parameters like link, unit, etc.

Here i am using this gem https://github.com/philnash/bitly

i am actually looking for **Clicks by Day**,
i tried

`Bitly.client.clicks("bitly_short_url").clicks_by_day`, works fine
but i need to change **Time Zone** value
i tried this

`Bitly.client.info({"link" =>"bitly_short_url", "timezone" => -6}).clicks_by_day`
and i am getting error.

Is there any other way to get result for different timezone?

Please help

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
Bitly.client.clicks({"link" =>"bitly_short_url", "timezone" => -6}).clicks_by_day
```

[info API](https://dev.bitly.com/links.html#v3_info) doesn't take `link` or `timezone` as parameters. But, [clicks API](https://dev.bitly.com/link_metrics.html#v3_link_clicks) takes that. You are passing parameters of *clicks API* to *info API*. That is the reason you are getting errors.

Comment: Thanks for reply, 
i tried that too, im getting this error `NoMethodError: undefined method 'match' for ["link", "short_url"]:Array`